# Magento Fatal error for __toString() in Mage.php

Tags: magento

Fatal error: Call to a member function __toString() on a non-object in /home/****/public_html/****/app/Mage.php on line 764 and below is the code near to 764 line

```
 public static function logException(Exception $e)
{
    if (!self::getConfig()) {
        return;
    }
    $file = self::getStoreConfig('dev/log/exception_file');
    self::log("\n" . $e->__toString(), Zend_Log::ERR, $file);
}
```

any reason why it is showing fatal error?

Comment: Fatal error is shown because $e is not an object. Check your custom functionality(modules) for Mage::logException statements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Exception $e is the string. It doesn't have the __toString() function.

You can try with :

```
print_r($e);
```

or

```
var_dump($e);
```

or

```
$e->getMessage();
```

^^